# My slack bot doesn't work properly when installed in a different workspace

Tags: bots, slack, workspace

I need your help!
I wrote my own slack bot and it works great in my workspace. In now I want to install it in other workspaces. As expected, I install my bot in another workspace through a script on the forwarding server with Oauth authorization, which generates a link with a button. By the way, here's a link, you can try https://redirect-server-url.herokuapp.com/slack/install
After installation, my bot is installed in the workspace, but the command output is not displayed, as it should be. For example, on the slash command "/ do", the bot should create a task and display the created task in the form of a message, but it creates the task (this can be seen from the fact that it is created in the database), but does not display it in the message. And this is exactly what happens if you install this bot in other workspaces. In my native workspace in which I tested the work of the bot - everything works fine. Can you please tell me how you can solve this problem?
p .s. Forgive me for my bad english.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you're using to publish the message, as you might have hardcoded a value there.